# Getting DatabaseException 'not authorized for query on db.collection' (code = 13) after mongo3 upgrade

Tags: mongodb, mlab, reactivemongo

I use the free MongoLab, and my database was upgraded to Mongo 3 over the weekend and now my client won't connect.  I keep getting a 'not authorized for query on db.collection.' error.

Mongolab says I should use Mongo 3 compatible driver (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/#driver-compatibility-changes).  I am using the scala ReactiveMongo client, version 0.11.7, which is supposed to support Mongo 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to add "?authMode=scram-sha1&rm.tcpNoDelay=true" to the end of my connection URI.  Now it looks like

`mongodb://user:password@host.mongolab.com:port/db?authMode=scram-sha1&rm.tcpNoDelay=true`